# Do duplicates affect the 'answered' ratio?

Tags: discussion

I don't even know if this is the right place to ask.

https://space.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates does not say anything if duplicates, that are marked as such, are counted as questions that haven been asked, but not answered.

Since this could have a negative effect on the 'answered' I'd rather delete my own question than to cause harm.

Do duplicates, which don't get answered because the original question got answered already, affect the 'answered' ratio?

The linked blog entry [1] says one shouldn't worry to much and I certainly agree that duplicates can be helpful.

[1] http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 2):

I believe that all questions which have at least on answer count as answered, even if they are later marked as duplicates.

Comment: I updated my question to explain what I was after. The duplicates may not get answered, because there's an answer already.

Comment: Ah... Just a minute...